# Salary "red flags" spotted with industrial PhD sponsor

Tags: salary, recruitment, tech-industry, research

I'm currently doing a STEM PhD at a top UK university that is partly sponsored by a private company. I have had all sorts of indications from numerous people that working for that company once my PhD is finished would be a good fit, and they have been very complimentary of my efforts since I have started working under their wing.

I have considered the possibility of getting a job with them afterwards, and my industrial supervisor has previously said that he would highly encourage me to apply for a specific position. He would be able to "fast-track" the interview process. This company has quite a few non-pay perks, such as private health insurance and a share of stocks after a certain amount of time working for them. They have also gained a lot of traction from various government funding sources, due to the importance of the work taking place at the company. They have even appeared in the news once or twice.

However, I seem to have picked up on a couple of red flags that are making me question whether getting a full-time job with them once my PhD is over would really be an optimal choice. For one thing, the job advertisements that they do offer disclose no information at all about the salary, other than "competitive". At one point I disclosed to my industrial supervisor that there was a postdoctoral position that I wanted to apply for, which did disclose the salary. When I asked him whether it was comparable to what I would earn if I started working at the company, I didn't get a direct answer. I simply got "I suggest you have a think about what you enjoy most." I would also like to say that I tried to soften my words a lot - I didn't simply ask "how much would you pay me", and I'm also hypersensitive that asking a company about what pay to expect could come across as rude or not being interested in the job for the "right" reasons.

To me this seems to suggest a "you don't do the job for the money" attitude; whilst in some professions this attitude is unfortunately all too common (like those managing hospitality-based professions such as teaching or healthcare) I can't help but feel that the salary is one of the most important deciding factors when looking for jobs to apply for, especially in high-tech research. My suspicions were further aroused when I was recently chatting to my industrial supervisor and his team leader at a conference, who said that they have been finding it very difficult to recruit experts in my area. He said that one of the candidates they recently interviewed were asking for £15k more than what the company was able to offer. He didn't disclose exactly what salary they were commanding, so I couldn't easily "work backwards" and find out how much I would be getting paid were I to work with them.

Both of these signs have led me to believe that the pay at such a position in the company would not be satisfactory, or commensurate with how much could be earned at in a different company (or country). Whilst I feel like the company have been really great to me during my PhD, I can't help but feel that these two signs I have picked up are not good ones. Does anyone else get a feeling that something isn't ideal here?

Comment: generally postdocs pay much less than industry. But here's the thing: the salary is what the salary is. You clearly aren't going to make them change it. And you aren't going to accept the job without knowing what it is. So just keep on doing what you're doing till you get an offer, then take that offer or don't. Stop trying to guess what the salary is and therefore what you should be doing about that. Look for work, apply for jobs including this one, and only take jobs that are good fits for you. Don't try to establish everything about the job before even applying.

Comment: "Don't try to establish everything about the job before even applying" - I would very much rather ascertain as much as I can before applying for a job so I can get a detailed picture of what working for them would actually be like. I don't want to end up applying for the job, get offered the job, then take the job and do it, only to realise 6 months down the line that it doesn't do what I want, or that there were unsavoury aspects of it that the company were economical with the truth about.

Comment: But the job offer will contain the salary.  You'll then know what salary they're going to offer you before you decide whether to accept or reject the offer.  It's not like you're going to accept the job and only find out what salary they're willing to pay you after you've been working there for 6 months.

Comment: sure, but the salary isn't one of those things. The salary is going to be in the offer. Also, interviewing is where you learn more about the job and get a detailed picture of what working for them would actually be like.

Comment: @KateGregory In my case, I'd say I already have a reasonably good idea of what working at the company is like, as I typically spend one day per week working with them, and I regularly consort with their academic and industrial collaborators. The nature of the work is highly independent, like academic research - but not quite as solitary.

Comment: If you "already have a reasonably good idea of what working at the company " and you'll know what the salary is, once any offer is made, what thing are you exactly concerned about?

Comment: @mattfreake I don't know. Not making as much money as I could be doing the same thing elsewhere, and settling in the same non-academic job for the rest of my life and becoming stagnant? I'm at quite a big crossroads in my life, trying to decide what exactly I want to do after my PhD.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly - allow me to sympathize - one of my Pet Peeves with Job listings is when people don't put a Salary range or band or some indication of what the position is paying.

This has lead to me inadvertently applying for a position that I was way overqualified for (thankfully, the Recruiter called me and then clarified what had happened) and it has lead me to walking out of an Interview (admittedly the interview was going badly and I had already decided I wasn't interested in working for them - but when their top salary band would be a $20K pay cut - I stopped and walked).

So - I hear you, I hear you with bells on.

That said, some companies and especially some industries operate like this - that an individuals Salary is based on the negotiation between the individual and the company, during the interview process.

In your situation - you have a good working relationship with the company, you feel you have a degree of 'debt' to the company for supporting you in your education - but you think you are going to be underpaid compared to industry rates, especially private industry rates.

If your sole focus in getting the biggest pay cheque (and let me be clear - absolutely nothing wrong with that) - then you are likely to be disappointed working for the public sector.

However, working for the public sector does have it's upsides - Job Security, networking and other intangible benefits.

My advice would be to at least go through the interview process, do your research on what the current market rates are - come up with a figure (make it reasonable) - add 10-20% on it (for negotiating down from) and make your best possible case:

- You are a known quantity - they already have seen the quality of your work and know what they are getting
- You know the team and can hit the ground running (on average, it takes 3-6 months when joining a new company to truly be effective)
- There's less risk in hiring you, even at a higher rate, than taking a punt on an unknown

Worst case scenario - they end the interview by saying that it's too much and they can't afford you - in which case they have pretty much made the decision for you.

Most likely though - both of you will negotiate and you may be able to hit upon a number that everyone is happy with.

Comment: Thanks for this. Luckily my partner company is a private organisation, and they have successfully attracted quite a bit of funding in their research area so this could put me in a good negotiating position salary-wise. However, my family have been saying "they've been good to you"; this is true, but as soon as I hear things like this, it makes me feel like I should accept a position with them out of courtesy. I'm still very much trying to figure out exactly what it is I want out of a career, whether I want to stay in academia or industry, or work at a role that interfaces the two, or neither!

Comment: If you're still trying to figure out exactly what you want, you may at some point just have to pick something, which will give you more knowledge about what you do or don't want. Taking a job which "6 months down the line that it doesn't do what I want" isn't necessarily a bad outcome.

Answer (score 2):

What they will offer depends on exactly what position they are hiring for, how hard it is to find candidates, what other companies are offering at that moment, how much they care about the fact that you already understand their processes, and a host of other imponderables. Plus possible negotiation.

First establish whether there is a job they will offer you at all. Then evaluate the offer based on all the factors from salary to commute to cost of living to whether the job and the people seem like they're going to be fun... and whatever else seems relevant. Then decide whether you want to accept, look elsewhere, or see if they can sweeten the deal a bit.

In that order.